# Flask-Admin Bootstrap 4 X-editable date causes error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4, flask-admin

@Joes I think I've found an error/bug in Flask-Admin's X-editable dates, but only in Bootstrap 4.

Notice in the below code, `template_mode='bootstrap3'` works fine, but `template_mode='bootstrap4' causes the error.

Code to reproduce the error:

```py
import os
import datetime

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask_admin as admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView


# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456789'

# Create in-memory database
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'sample_db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Instantiate the admin class with Bootstrap mode
# admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin = admin.Admin(app, 'Example', template_mode='bootstrap4')


# Models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    email = db.Column(db.Unicode(64))
    date_added = db.Column(db.Date)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class UserAdmin(ModelView):
    column_searchable_list = ('name', 'email')
    column_editable_list = ('name', 'email', 'date_added')
    column_display_pk = True

    can_set_page_size = True
    # the number of entries to display in the list view
    page_size = 5


# Add Flask-Admin views
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))

# Flask normal views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


def build_sample_db():
    """Populate a small db with some example entries"""

    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    first_names = [
        'Harry', 'Amelia', 'Oliver', 'Jack', 'Isabella', 'Charlie','Sophie', 'Mia',
    ]
    last_names = [
        'Brown', 'Smith', 'Patel', 'Jones', 'Williams', 'Johnson', 'Taylor', 'Thomas',
    ]

    for i in range(len(first_names)):
        user = User()
        user.name = first_names[i] + " " + last_names[i]
        user.email = first_names[i].lower() + "@example.com"
        user.date_added = datetime.date.today()
        db.session.add(user)

    db.session.commit()
    return


# Build a sample db on the fly, if one does not exist yet.
app_dir = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
database_path = os.path.join(app_dir, app.config['DATABASE_FILE'])
os.remove(database_path)
if not os.path.exists(database_path):
    build_sample_db()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here's what the Flask-Admin view looks like with Bootstrap 4, before the error:
[image]

Here's what the error looks like in the JavaScript console, when I click on the "editable" date field:
[image]

Here's what it looks like using the `template_mode='bootstrap3'` (i.e. what it's supposed to do):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's related to [this issue](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/2022) and the `data-template` that needs to be removed.

Flask-Admin doesn't remove the `data-template` for this date field since it's just given a `data-role='x-editable'` instead lf `x-editable-combodate`.

There are at least two ways of fixing this (in the JavaScript "forms.js" or in the XEditableWidget class's `get_kwargs()` method). I chose to fix it in the `get_kwargs()` method as follows:

```py
class XEditableWidget(object):
    # ...
    def get_kwargs(self, field, kwargs):
        """
            Return extra kwargs based on the field type.
        """
        if field.type == 'StringField':
            kwargs['data-type'] = 'text'
        # ...
        elif field.type == 'DateField':
            kwargs['data-type'] = 'combodate'
            kwargs['data-format'] = 'YYYY-MM-DD'

            # Remove the following so JavaScript doesn't have to do it
            # kwargs['data-template'] = 'YYYY-MM-DD'

            # Use the following so it adjusts the template
            kwargs['data-role'] = 'x-editable-combodate'
```

Here's what happens in the "form.js" file on page-load (i.e. where the `data-template` attribute is removed, in the latest Flask-Admin "master" branch):

```js
            case 'x-editable':
                // No removal of the "data-template" attribute
                $el.editable({
                    params: overrideXeditableParams,
                    combodate: {
                        // prevent minutes from showing in 5 minute increments
                        minuteStep: 1,
                        maxYear: 2030,
                    }                    
                });
                return true;
            case 'x-editable-combodate':
                // Fixes bootstrap4 issue where data-template breaks bs4 popover.
                // https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/2022
                let template  = $el.data('template');
                $el.removeAttr('data-template');
                $el.editable({
                    params: overrideXeditableParams,
                    template: template,
                    combodate: {
                        // prevent minutes from showing in 5 minute increments
                        minuteStep: 1,
                        maxYear: 2030,
                    }
                });
                return true;
```

The resulting popover is a tiny bit ugly now, for some reason, but functionally it works at least!
[image: Working Bootstrap 4 X-editable popover]

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the answer. How do we implement this in our flask admin view? 

class MyModelView(ModelView):
     ###


In the function written by you, should there be an Else with:  super(CustomWidget, self).get_kwargs(field, kwargs)? Or is that n/a/ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me. Added the below function before loading Admin(**).

```
def patch_admin_datetime():
    from flask_admin.form.fields import DateTimeField
    def patched_init(self, label=None, validators=None, format=None, **kwargs):
        format = format or '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        super(DateTimeField, self).__init__(label, validators, format, **kwargs)
    DateTimeField.__init__ = patched_init

 patch_admin_datetime()

 #Admin(**) ->
```